# How to synchronize page update? (flet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flet

I have the code:

```
def main(page: Page):
    global views_count
    vf = open("views", "r+")
    views_count = int(vf.readline().replace("\n", ''))
    def route_change(e: ft.RouteChangeEvent):
        global views_count
        global vf
        views = ft.Container(ft.Text(f"Views: {views_count + 1}"))
        page.update()

    page.add(views)
            views_count += 1
            vf = open("views", "w")
            vf.close()
            vf = open("views", "a+")
            vf.write(str(views_count))
            vf.close()
            vf = open("views", "r")
            views_count = int(vf.readline().replace("\n", ''))
            page.update()
```

Everything works well, but if, for example, user 1 goes to the site, he sees the value 1, then user 2 goes to the site and sees the value 2, but user 1 will still have the value 1. How to update the value in real time? (No page reload). Thanks in advance, sorry for bad English

I tried writing the value to a file (It is in the example), and running a page update cycle:

```
while True:
    page.update()
```

But the page simply stopped responding to clicks.